# Possible to generate auto-complete from a namespace object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Imagine I have a `.env` file that looks like this.

```
EARTH_SYNONYM1 = "World"
EARTH_SYNONYM2 = "Planet"
EARTH_SYNONYM3 = "Globe"
```

I've managed to load it into a namespace.

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
from types import SimpleNamespace
from dotenv.main import dotenv_values # dotenv package needs to be installed.


def json_to_python(json_str):
    return json.loads(json_str, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))


dotenv_path = Path(".") / ".env"
dotenv_vars_list = dotenv_values(dotenv_path)
dotenv_vars_as_json = json.dumps(dotenv_vars_list)
dotenv_vars = json_to_python(dotenv_vars_as_json)

print(dotenv_vars)
```

Which prints

```
namespace(EARTH_SYNONYM1='World', EARTH_SYNONYM2='Planet', EARTH_SYNONYM3='Globe')
```

Now I can do things like

```
print(f"Hello {dotenv_vars.EARTH_SYNONYM1}")
```

Which prints

```
Hello World
```

What I would love to accomplish is turning this into a class module (I think).
I'd like to

```
import dotenv_vars
```

And then type

```
dotenv_vars.
```

and be presented with a list of auto-complete options.
Continuing this example, each of the `EARTH_SYNONYMx` would show as auto-complete options.

How can I make the namespace object provide auto-complete?

Comment: By writing it as a python file? That's what you would normally import...

Comment: Why don't you just rename your `.env` file to a `.py` file and import it.  A module namespace is as good as any...

Comment: The real `.env` file is being used as a true local `.env` file.  i.e. - it is holding database usernames and passwords and is in the `.gitignore` for git commits.

Comment: I guess what you guys are saying is create something like `secretstuff.py` and add it to `.gitignore` and import it like any other python file? It's really nice having a `.env` sitting there and knowing exactly what it's about and why.

Comment: Wait, why is autocomplete so important in the first place then?

Comment: It's not super important.  Just a fun challenge I couldn't solve. Really I was just trying to provide context.  Maybe this question should have started with "I have this namespace..." 

Answer (score 1):

I always thought dotenv is a pretty silly library and overcomplicating something that is so simple. Load your vars into a module namespace with Python's import system.

```
import imp
dotenv_vars = imp.load_source('dotenv_vars', '.env')
```

Comment: Wow.  Cool!  
That negates all the code above. Much simpler. Thanks! 
Do you have a trick for the auto-complete?

Comment: I'm not familiar with visual-studio-code IDE so I can't comment on its autocompletion features (or lack thereof). It's probably just working statically, and asking it to work with dynamically loaded data is like asking for magic.

Comment: Well, the answer you provided here is magic. So I thought maybe you had another spell up your sleeve.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you're not on Windows, you could make a `dotenv_vars.py` symbolic link pointing to `.env` target. Then `import dotenv_vars` as usual. An IDE auto-complete will likely work if given that kind of encouragement.

Comment: Where do you think you would put this in the install step? Or are you just saying put this in onstart.py for example.